# TSQL Running Totals aggregate from sum of previous rows

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions, rows

Not sure how to word this.  Say i have a select returing this.

```
Name, month, amount
John, June, 5
John, July,6
John, July, 3
John August, 10
```

and I want to aggregate and report beggining blance for each month.

name, month, beggining balance.

```
john, may, 0
john, june, 0
john, july, 5
john, august, 14
john, September, 24
```

I can do this in excel with cell formulas, but how can I do it in SQL without storing values somewhere? I have another table with fiscal months i can do a left outer join with so all months are reported, just not sure how to aggregate from prior months in sql.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? sql server, mysql?

Comment: sorry TSQL SQL Server. updated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  This is very important as 2012 has functionality that 2008 doesn't, and 2008 has functionality that 2005 doesn't.  Or perhaps its Compact Edition?  The half-cartessian-product answer that you have chosen is highly inefficient as the amount of data grows *(as stated in the answer)*.  But to know the best alternative requires knowing what options you have; it involves knowing which version of SQL Server you are actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
name
, month
, (select sum(balance) from mytable 
   where mytable.month < m.month and mytable.name = m.name) as starting_balance
from mytable m
group by name, month
```

This is not as nice as windowing functions, but since they vary from database to database, you'd need to tell us which system you are using.

***And*** it's an inline subquery, which is not very performant. But at least it's easy to understand what's going on !

Comment: Thank you. Need to test this out. Marking you as answer since first. Did not want to complicate the question, but what if there is business complexity - for example, I want to add a percentage of the prior month and that percentage is dictated by John's years of service with the company as of the prior month. Can I do that in a function inline?

Comment: yes, you could, but it would quickly become difficult to read and slow (since the inline  SQL is executed for *each row*). I'd then look into a join or the RANK() and OVER() functions in Sql Server. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx for more info.

Comment: It is not that this is an inline function that is the problem, SQL Server is excellent at expanding these out when generating the query plan.  The problem is that it is a half cartessian product.  *(Each subsequent row is joined to all the preceding rows.  This means that a running total over 100 rows is actually processing 1+2+..+100 rows of data, 5050 rows in total...)*  Later versions of SQL Server allow *(As @davek states)* use of the OVER clause which can significantly imporve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grouping like this

```
SELECT NAME, MONTH , SUM(Balance) FROM table GROUP BY NAME, MONTH
```

Comment: the OP requires sum of the data belonging to *preceeding* months

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your months are represented as dates, this will give you the running total.

```
select t1.name, t1.month, sum(t2.amount)
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2 
     on t1.name = t2.name
     and t1.month>t2.month
group by t1.name, t1.month
```